# I want to start the app on boot but wont get launched

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi am trying to start the application on boot. App starts whenever boot completed but application launched and activity screen came to front. I want to start the app on boot but wont get launched. i included the manifest and BootUpReceiver.java .. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.startapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".StartApp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">  
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>         
        </activity>

    </application>
<manifest>
```

BootUpReceiver.Java

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
     Intent i = new Intent(context, StartApp.class);  
     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? you are saying that it works fine and on the other instance you are saying that it won't get launched. Can you explain a bit more or I mis-understood you.

Comment: Have you opened activity in BootUpReceiver class?

Comment: I would set the permission outside the receiver

Comment: @nisha Yes, I updated my code with BootUpReceiver

Comment: @SPK: No i can't find the answer.

Comment: Just try with this i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Thanks i tried but app launched immediately after boot...

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to start a Service which runs in the background instead of an Activity.
There is a question regarding that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android).

Comment: @maxi No i don't want to start service. am trying to start app in background without launching after boot.

Comment: You can't start Activity in the background, you can run only Service in the background and that can start an Activity for you if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are testing this on a HTC and have "Fast boot" enabled (`Settings -> Power -> Fast boot`). In that case no `BOOT_COMPLETED` will be sent.

Some more information in my question [Detect if HTC “Fast boot” is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8658862/562935)