# Any way to know if Device booted from a fastboot?

Tags: android, android-intent

Ever since HTC started using Fastboot settings, apps depending on

> **android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED**

struggle to boot along with the device boot on HTC devices. I have a similar application which depends on the above intent action. But since HTC does its power off and power on differently by using fastboot(other term used - Hibernation) my App never get to work normally. 
I tried using [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) and [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON), but it seemed to be more of hack than a fix for my problem.
Do any of you came across same kind of problem and found a better way to deal with it? Please help.
SKU

Comment: HTC fast-boot by design does not broadcast the event. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411731/how-to-get-boot-complete-intent-in-htc-when-i-use-poweroff-for-reboot) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658862/detect-if-htc-fast-boot-is-enabled) may be helpful. [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525907/htcs-fast-boot-is-not-broadcasting-boot-completed-intent-nor-wiping-intents-f) [Duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411731/how-to-get-boot-complete-intent-in-htc-when-i-use-poweroff-for-reboot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the intent action that HTC uses during Fastboot Power On and Power Off. I thought of sharing it here as it may be useful for someone else who is facing same problem as me.

Here is the intent action you need to register in AndroidManifest.xml under your Receiver.

```
<receiver android:name="com.my.app.MyReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope it was helpful

Comment: Can you please explain me the difference between BOOT_COMPLETED and QUICKBOOT_POWERON? Under what circumstances is QUICKBOOT_POWERON intent sent?

Comment: Is this still useful nowadays to use `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` ? If not, from which API ?

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone is programming with an HTC Droid DNA as their target, I discovered that its "fast boot" doesn't send "**android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON**", but rather sends "**com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON**".

I hope this helps someone somewhere as it took me hours to figure this out.

Comment: I hate it when OEM just go about changing things without giving damn about the developers. Using "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" by itself is not a standard way of doing it, now they have changed it again. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Is this still useful nowadays to use `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` ? If not, from which API ?